# Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error 0x8000ffff

Tags: java, multithreading, browser, swt, xulrunner

I am getting below Exception while running my program. It works fine when I use SWT.NONE instead of SWT.MOZILLA. But I need to use SWT.MOZZILLA, so I can manipulate the browser settings(like proxy settings) or request headers.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error 0x8000ffff
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.error(Mozilla.java:2815)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initProfile(Mozilla.java:2617)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:770)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:101)
at OrderThread.openBrowser(MultiThreadBrowser.java:34)
at OrderThread.run(MultiThreadBrowser.java:26)
```

Here is my program, in this program, I am using XULRunner version 3.6.28, 32 bit which I downloaded [here](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/). I would really appreciate your response on this.

Adding additional information that, it works fine when I run this in single thread.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.ProgressAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.ProgressEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class MultiThreadBrowser {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String xulrunnerDir = "C:\\xulrunner-3.6.28.en-US.win32\\xulrunner";
        System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath", xulrunnerDir);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            OrderThread ot = new OrderThread();
            ot.start();
        }
    }
}

class OrderThread extends Thread {

    boolean loaded = false;

    public void run() {
        openBrowser();
    }

    public void openBrowser() {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.MOZILLA);
        browser.setUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");
        shell.open();

        browser.addProgressListener(new ProgressAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void completed(ProgressEvent event) {
                if (!loaded) {
                    loaded = true;
                    event.display.timerExec(5000, new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("Loaded!!!");
                            shell.close();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        while (display.getShells().length > 0) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this [Mozilla link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XULRunner_1.8.0.4_Release_Notes) and done the `xulrunner.exe --register-global` command?

Comment: I didn't, but I just did it. it didn't solve this issue.

Comment: Does [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=174395) help?

Comment: Could you please explain it little more, how it can help?